# Is there a more concise way to create pairs from a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list where `x[0][0] = position of x[0][1]` in a string **S**.

```
x  = [[157, 'Start_Summary'], [1228, 'End_Summary'], [1233, 'Start_Skills'], [1540, 'End_Skills'], [1925, 'Start_Work'], [2392, 'profile_start'], [4378, 'profile_end'], [4451, 'profile_start'], [5368, 'profile_end'], [5759, 'profile_start'], [7000, 'profile_end'], [7000, 'End_Work']]
```

I want to create a list of tuples such that the output list would be pairs of positions of Start and End of a particular type of tag -

```
y = [(157,1228),(1233,1540),(1925,7000),(2392,4378),(4451,5368),(5759,7000)]
```

I have tried using *for loop* and *if-else* statements, but I am looking for a pythonic way to generate such a list.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have written to achieve this.

Comment: While you have mixed formats in the tags (`profile_end` vs `End_work`) this is going to be difficult to parse nicely. Where did the initial list come from?

Comment: IMHO, it is too complex for a list comprehension to be possible. You should show your current attempt.

Comment: Can you clarify the logic in more detail, instead of us needing to infer it from a long line of samples?

Comment: looks like an event log, always there is a `start` before an `end`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can store your data in a `collections.defaultdic`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

positions = {'start', 'end'}
for n, s in x:
    p, t = s.lower().split('_')
    if p not in positions:
        p, t = t, p
    data[t].append(n)

[tuple(v[i: i + 2] ) for v in data.values() for i in range(0, len(v)-1, 2)]
```

output:

```
[(157, 1228),
 (1233, 1540),
 (1925, 7000),
 (2392, 4378),
 (4451, 5368),
 (5759, 7000)]
```

Comment: I made the same mistake. This doesn't work as it assumes start/end pairs are together. Compare your output to the question.